# Concatenate string to build formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to build VBA code to enter a formula to sum up a range.

I want a formula in cell E30

```
=SUM(E10:E20)
```

```vb
Sub calTotalOneOffExpense()

Dim startRow As Integer
Dim endRow As Integer
startRow = 10
endRow = 20

Range("E30:E30").Select
Dim sFormula As String

sFormula = "=Sum(E" & startRow & ":E" & endRow & ")"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        sFormula

End Sub
```

The formula in E30 becomes

```
=SUM('E10':'E20')
```

Comment: so formula in E30 becomes =SUM('E10':'E20') . I wanted it to be =SUM(E10:E20)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand the difference between Formula and FormulaR1C1. You should study the documentation. Formula expects A1-style notation.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sum(E" & startRow & ":E" & endRow & ")"
```

FormulaR1C1 expects R1C1-style notation

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(R" & startRow & "C5:R" & endRowRow & "C5)"
```

which is equivalent ​to

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sum($E$10:$E$20)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `.FormulaR1C1`

Use `.Formula` instead.

```
sFormula = "=SUM(E" & startRow & ":E" & endRow & ")"
ActiveCell.Formula = sFormula
```